# how many types for reporting in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

how many types for reporting  in vb.net.iam beginner and i want to know how many types for generating reports...i know about crystal report which provided by sap company.i want to know more about and more easy way to quickly generate reports 
how many types for reporting  in vb.net.iam beginner and i want to know how many types for generating reports...i know about crystal report which provided by sap company.i want to know more about and more easy way to quickly generate reports
how many types for reporting  in vb.net.iam beginner and i want to know how many types for generating reports...i know about crystal report which provided by sap company.i want to know more about and more easy way to quickly generate reports

Comment: Any answer to this question would be opinion based. Google, pick one, try the code. If you have a problem with the code, post again.

Comment: I would recommend you ask this question in the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) community of Stack Exchange.  You are more likely to get better answers there, as the Stack Overflow community is more focused on helping developers with specific questions about programming and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

According to Deep Thought, it's 42.